# Emacs Lisp - mapcar doesn't apply function to all elements?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a function that takes a list and replaces some elements. I have constructed it as a closure so that the free variable cannot be modified outside of the function.

```
(defun transform (elems)
  (lexical-let ( (elems elems) )
    (lambda (seq)
      (let (e)
    (while (setq e (car elems))
      (setf (nth e seq) e)
      (setq elems (cdr elems)))
    seq))))
```

I call this on a list of lists.

```
(defun tester (seq-list)
  (let ( (elems '(1 3 5)) )
    (mapcar (transform elems) seq-list)))

(tester (list (reverse (number-sequence 1 10)) 
          '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")))
=> ((10 1 8 3 6 5 4 3 2 1) ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"))
```

It does not seem to apply the function to the second element of the list provided to tester(). However, if I explicitly apply this function to the individual elements, it works...

```
(defun tester (seq-list)
  (let ( (elems '(1 3 5)) )
    (list (funcall (transform elems) (car seq-list))
          (funcall (transform elems) (cadr seq-list)))))

(tester (list (reverse (number-sequence 1 10)) 
          '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")))
=> ((10 1 8 3 6 5 4 3 2 1) ("a" 1 "c" 3 "e" 5))
```

If I write a simple function using the same concepts as above, mapcar seems to work... What could I be doing wrong?

```
(defun transform (x)
  (lexical-let ( (x x) )
    (lambda (y) 
      (+ x y))))

(defun tester (seq)
  (let ( (x 1) )
    (mapcar (transform x) seq)))

(tester (list 1 3))    
=> (2 4)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed-over variable `elems` is set to nil after the first invocation of the closure; so all subsequent calls only see nil.  Your second example works because each instance of `transform` produces a new closure.

This should work:

```
(defun transform (elems)
  (lexical-let ((elems elems))
    (lambda (seq)
      (dolist (e elems seq)
        (setf (nth e seq) e)))))
```

Comment: dolist is nice! I guess lexical-let doesn't protect free variables from modification... (and my second example wasn't close enough to the first I guess for me to catch it...).